# SSRS 2012 ODBC Driver architecture mismatch on remote computer, works locally

Tags: ssrs, odbc, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS 2012 server (Windows 2012) with Ingres ODBC drivers installed, ODBC entries have been configured in the 32 bit (`SysWOW64`) ODBC manager.  Reports ran locally on the server run without a problem and are speedy.  When I run the reports remotely via SSRS web interface I get the following error:

> `ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application`

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the datasource on the server had a slightly different DSN to the one I was using locally.  It looks like the datasource had been deployed to the server and broke reporting...